# degree of a polynomial over complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $\alpha,\beta\neq 0$ be two complex numbers, and $f(z)$ is a polynomial function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\alpha$ whenever $z^5=\beta$. What can you say about degree of the polynomial $f(z)$..

All that i can see is $\omega\sqrt[5]{\beta}$ where $\omega$ is a fifth root of unity is a solution for $f(z)-\alpha$.. So, i can say that $f(z)$ has degree atleast $5$..

Can we say anything more than this?

Comment: Whenever $z^5\beta$... what?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : Corrected...

Comment: $f$ could also be constant.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : Yes it can be. In that case degree is $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can say that $z^5 - \beta$ divides (i.e., is a factor of) $f(z) - \alpha$. So $$
f(z) = (z^5 - \beta) g(z) + \alpha$$
 for some polynomial $g$.

(Note that this includes @LinAlgMan's solution, in the sense that $g$ could be the zero polynomial.)

Comment: OK.. I do not know what to ask.. In case of non constant polynomial degree is atleast $5$.. Nothing more than this rihgt?

Comment: Well...I don't know. The problem says "Can we say anything more than this?" and I guess that I did so. Whether YOU can say more than *I* did is an open question that only you can answer. :)

Comment: :P Yes I agree that you said more than what i did.. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) = \alpha$ be the constant polynomial. Then trivialy $f(\omega^j \beta^{1/5}) = \alpha$ but $f$ is of degree $0$.

Comment: This is one solution for sure.. Can we say any thing more than this?